# Removing AppArmor

Tags: kernel, uninstall, apparmor

I have MySQL installed in my development machine, where I just don't need any additional  security measure.

I want to move MySQL Data files to another partition, which implies a lot of change in AppAmor config, that I don't want to do since it's too much work for a simple development machine and I really don't need it.

My question is: is it safe to remove AppArmor without any side-effects to the system?

Like I said, security in this case is not really a concern.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the way to go. Apparmor is there for a reason. And it is not that difficult. (the change is -identical- to what you did in /etc/mysql/my.cnf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be safe to remove AppArmor in the sense of the word. You would be disabling a security system designed to be in place for protecting you. So it would indeed make you less safe. What you want to know is: yes you can remove it without side-effects but lessen that system's security with it.

But the changes to apparmor are quite minimal, if you just want to move the MySQL DataDir to another partition. In addition I would recommend moving it to */srv/mysql* and mount your partition either to */srv* or to */srv/mysql* for that reason (depending if you have other services on that box you want to put into */srv*).

Reason behind is, that ubuntu states the */srv* mountpoint/directory the place for your own (custom) service data to be deployed (*srv stands for service. Should contain server specific services related data. For example, /srv/cvs contains CVS related data.*)

The changes to apparmor are quite minimalistic:

*vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld* and search for /var/lib/mysql and insert:

```
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  # new location of datadir
  /srv/mysql/ r,
  /srv/mysql/** rwk,
```

That is enough to satisfy apparmor and you can leave it in place without needing to fiddle around with uninstalling it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Always a pleasure.

Comment: +1, but if I may remark: I love `vi` but I generally suggest to use `nano` in my answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove AppArmor without immediately killing the system. Nothing relies on it to function.

But it is there for a reason. If security really isn't a concern, that's fair enough, but if you're just doing it for a quick convenience, consider learning how to adapt the rules.

Comment: Ok, I'll look a little bit more on it.

Comment: Ubuntu's 18.04 Bionic Beaver **snapd** (and all the snaps) relies on apparmor. Not sure about Focal Fosa.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific question replace `$applicationname` with `mysqld`

The best practice way to disable apparmor for a single application is

`sudo aa-complain $applicationname`

or

`sudo aa-complain /path/to/$applicationname`.

If you install `apparmor-utils` you can use `aa-cleanprof $applicationname` to wipe the profile clean and it won't stop anything.

Keep in mind that you can easily generate a profile while in development so that you know exactly what your application needs if you were to deploy it in production.

You can install `apparmor-utils` and use `aa-cleanprof`, `aa-autodep $applicationname`, `aa-genprof $applicationname` and `aa-logprof` to easily build a profile specific to your use of the application.