# Change mySQL datadir: problems with apparmor

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I'm trying to change mysql data directory to a zfs dataset.

I've changed mysql.cnf and /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld, but still have errors. I get the errors **even when I try to stop apparmor** service with `systemctl stop apparmor.service`. I have also tried creating a link to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/disable.

I've also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295457/mysql-datadir-on-different-hard-drive) (don't understand why it should work, but tried anyway to avoid my question being marked as duplicated) and it failed.

It seems apparmor is not obeying me anymore. Am I doing something wrong, or it's something related with [the Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity)?

This is my exit of `apparmor_status` after `systemctl stop apparmor.service`

```
15 profiles are loaded.
15 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/bin/lxc-start
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/lxd/lxd-bridge-proxy
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//snap_update_ns
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   lxc-container-default
   lxc-container-default-cgns
   lxc-container-default-with-mounting
   lxc-container-default-with-nesting
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

These are the error in `journalctl -xe` after a failed attempt to start mysql:

```
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3967/status" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=114 ouid=114
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=114 ouid=0
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3967/status" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=114 ouid=114
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.499:95): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3967/status" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.499:96): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" 
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.499:97): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3967/status" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.675:98): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask=
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=114 ouid
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=114 ouid
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=114 ouid
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.683:99): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask=
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.683:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/mantra.lower-test" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra audit[3967]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/ibdata1" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=114 ouid=114
ene 06 12:56:32 mantra kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515239792.715:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/pit/mysql/ibdata1" pid=3967 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="wr" denie
ene 06 12:56:33 mantra systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

What could I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Datadir on different hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295457/mysql-datadir-on-different-hard-drive)

Comment: I've tried that too but mysql still not working. I need a method to stop apparmor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved! I still don't know why apparmor was not stopped but I've been able to change datadir.

The problem was that I was creating a backup file of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` (ie, `usr.sbin.mysql.backup`) in the same directory and it was being processed *after* the file I was modifying, so the changes were overwritten. Big facepalm.

I found useful information in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294672/removing-apparmor). After installing `apparmor-utils` and running `aa-complain` I got an error of "duplicated profile" or something like that and I was able to realize what the problem was.

I still got apparmor errors about /proc/NNN/status but I think they were there before the change. Everything is working fine now.